# On the subgroups properties of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G:=A_5$. I want to know why all of the elements of $2$-Sylow subgroups and $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are not commutative?

Comment: But $xy \not = yx$ in your case, so how is this a counterexample? Moreover you need all elements of the subgroup commuting, not just a single pair

Comment: Do you mean why the subgroups do not commute? Because All Sylow subgroups of $A_5$ are commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you mean it is not true that (all of the elements of) the Sylow $2$ and $3$ subgroups commute.

For this it would be sufficient to find any pair $x,y$ from the respective subgroups that don't commute...

You had done this...  Since $(1 2)(3 4)$ and $(1 2 3)$ don't commute, you're done.